# jboss datasource statistics JMX monitoring - inconsistent information

Tags: sql, jboss, datasource, jmx

I have defined two datasources in *-ds.xml on jboss 4.2.3 (redhat 4.3)
Both datasources are identical. Only jndi-name differ
Each defines min=max=10

```
<xa-datasource>
 <jndi-name>com.trax.hibernate.DataSource</jndi-name>
 <track-connection-by-tx>true</track-connection-by-tx>
 <isSameRM-override-value>false</isSameRM-override-value>
 <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
 <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl10</xa-datasource-property>
 <xa-datasource-property name="User"> xxxx </xa-datasource-property>
 <xa-datasource-property name="Password"> xxxx </xa-datasource-property>
 <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
 <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
 <prefill>true</prefill>
 <blocking-timeout-millis>60000</blocking-timeout-millis>
 <ih3e-timeout-minutes>15</ih3e-timeout-minutes>
 <valid-connection-checker-class-name> org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleValidConnectionChecker </valid-connection-checker-class-name>
 <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from gtw_cust</check-valid-connection-sql>
 <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
 <no-tx-separate-pools/>
</xa-datasource>

<xa-datasource>
 <jndi-name>AuditTrail.DataSource</jndi-name>
 <track-connection-by-tx>true</track-connection-by-tx>
 <isSameRM-override-value>false</isSameRM-override-value>
 <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
 <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl10</xa-datasource-property>
 <xa-datasource-property name="User">xxxx</xa-datasource-property>
 <xa-datasource-property name="Password"> xxxx </xa-datasource-property>
 <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
 <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
 <prefill>true</prefill>
 <blocking-timeout-millis>60000</blocking-timeout-millis>
 <ih3e-timeout-minutes>15</ih3e-timeout-minutes>
 <valid-connection-checker-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name>
 <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from gtw_cust</check-valid-connection-sql>
 <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
 <no-tx-separate-pools/>
</xa-datasource>
```

The problem:
On jmx-console, name=com.trax.hibernate.DataSource,service=ManagedConnectionPool, the information shows 20 connections, not 10 as expected.

I would expect the max value of created connections to be 10 (MaxSize).
Here is seems that the number of actual connection is double MaxSize, and connections were created and destroyed (40 created and 20 destroyed)

What am I doing wrong? How can you explain this?

```
com.trax.hibernate.DataSource:
AvailableConnectionCount    20
ConnectionCount           20
MinSize                      10
MaxSize                      10
MaxConnectionsInUseCount    11
InUseConnectionCount              0
ConnectionCreatedCount  40
ConnectionDestroyedCount    20

AuditTrail.DataSource:
AvailableConnectionCount    10
ConnectionCount           10
MinSize                      10
MaxSize                      10
MaxConnectionsInUseCount    8
InUseConnectionCount              0
ConnectionCreatedCount  20
ConnectionDestroyedCount    10
```

Comment: When deploying only the datasource without the application the two datasources create exactly MaxSize connections. only when the application is deployed, the first datasource creates double MaxSize connections, so it is indeed dependent on how the application uses the datasource, although both datasources are defined as XA - oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because of the property `<no-tx-separate-pools/>`. See the documentation for XA Data Sources, in JBoss Server Configuration Guide:

> `<no-tx-separate-pools>`
>
> Pool transactional and non-transactinal connections separately
>
> Warning
>
> Using this option will cause your total pool size to be twice max-pool-size, because two actual pools will be created.

http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.3/html-single/Server_Configuration_Guide/index.html#id2947572

Comment: OK, i can see i'm using that property. however, i'm using it in both datasources, and only the first is doubled...

Comment: I'd suppose that's because you are using the AuditTrail connection in a different way than the main pool. Is there anything special in the AuditTrail? Is it part of the main transaction?

Comment: Well, the first datasource is used through Hibernate and jboss JTA, while the other is used by another (third party) software library, so you may be right... any idea on how i can verify that?

Comment: Not sure. Perhaps looking at the documentation of this third party library. See if it tries to join an existing JTA transaction or not. I bet it doesn't. Another way is, of course, just to remove this option and watch the pool :-)

Comment: OK, now regarding the ConnectionDestroyedCount value... why should the datasource create double the connections it needs and then destroy 50%? i would expect it never to create more than MaxSize...